# Prove that for any natural number $n$ there exists a prime number $p$ greater than $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that for any natural number *n* there exists a natural **prime** number *p* , such that $ p>n $. How can I prove that ? Thank you.

Comment: The "proof verification" tag is for when you have provided a proof and want to know if it is correct.

Comment: This question is equivalent to prove that there is infinity of prime numbers!

Comment: If not, then all the prime numbers will be less than a fixed integer. So..

Comment: Here is thought, prove that there exist $ \; k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \; k \ge n \; $, where $ \; 2^k + 1 \; $ or $ \; 2^k - 1 \; $ is prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing prove that there are infinite number of primes,you can use the Euclid proof imagine that there are $n$ primes and name the $k$-th prime $p_k$ than the number $t=p_1p_2\cdots p_{n-1}p_n+1$ isn't divisible by any prime $p_k$ where $1\leq k\leq n$ so there is another prime which divides $t$.Now it's easy to show that $p_k> k$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ since the first prime is $p_1=2$ and $p_{k+1}>p_k$

Answer (score 3):

Think about the prime factors of $n!+1$.

Comment: I think this answer is just fine, but maybe it is the case to make it less cryptical since it was marked as low-quality.

Answer (score 3):

Use Bertrand's postulate for the number $n$ or any number greater than it.

Answer (score 0):

We know that there are infinitely many natural prime numbers.
Now, for some natural number n, let there do not exist any natural prime p such that $p \gt n$. This implies that all prime numbers are less than or equal to the natural number n. Since, even the total number of natural numbers less than or equal to n is finite, the number of natural prime numbers must be finite which contradicts the above fact.
Hence our assumption is false, therefore its negation must be true i.e., for every natural number n, there exists atleast one natural prime p such that $p \gt n.$

Comment: This isn't better or worse. I just proved that the statement "There are infinitely many prime numbers" implies that "for every natural number n, there exists a natural prime p such that p>n." to show that these two statements are equivalent though i didn't prove the converse because that is very obvious. Since the proof of existence of infinite primes by Euclid is well known, one can use that to prove this implied statement.